# ASP - OR statement not working

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following statement which is not working, im wondering if someone could help me out and tell me where im going wrong

```
<% If ((urlFilename <> "calculators.aspx") Or (urlFilename <> "case-studies.aspx")) Then %>
    <div class="block-quote">
    </div>
<% End If %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code between If and End If will always fire because one of those tests will always be true.

If urlFilename = "home.aspx" both conditions are satisfied, and the code will fire.

If urlFilename = "calculators.aspx" the first condition fails, but the second is met, and the code will fire.

If urlFilename = "case-studies.aspx" the first condition is met...

Comment: Oh ok ... How would i only do it if the URl was equal to either of those filenames?

Comment: I don't know classic ASP, but maybe:

`<% If ((urlFilename <> "calculators.aspx") Then %>
<% If (urlFilename <> "case-studies.aspx")) Then %> 
    <div class="block-quote">
    </div>
<% End If %>
<% End If %>`